# c popen won't catch stderr

Tags: c, popen, stderr

I'm trying to use `popen()` to catch the stderr of a call, but of course it doesn't seem to be doing that.  Any ideas?

My code looks more or less like this:

```
popen("nedit", "r");
```

But I'm getting all this garbage about non-utf8 on my screen...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`popen` gives you a file handle on a process' stdout, not its stderr. Its first argument is interpreted as a shell command, so you can do redirections in it:

```
FILE *p = popen("prog 2>&1", "r");
```

or, if you don't want the stdout at all,

```
FILE *p = popen("prog 2>&1 >/dev/null", "r");
```

(Any other file besides `/dev/null` is acceptable as well.)

Comment: If we do not want the output at all, couldn't we do `popen(..., "w");` instead?

Comment: `"w"` will give you a FILE you can write to to provide stdin to the program.  Both stdout and stderr will continue to go to the same place.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to discard all of the error messages, then you can use:

```
popen("nedit 2>/dev/null", "r");
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need both stdout and stderr streams, you can open an extra pipe and redirect child stderr to it:

```
if (pipe(pfd) < 0)
    return -1;
    
perr = fdopen(pfd[0], "r");

snprintf(command, LINE_LEN, "... 2>&%d", pfd[1]);

if (pout = popen(command, "r")) {
    close(pfd[1]);

    while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN, pout) != NULL)
        ...
    
    while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN, perr) != NULL)
        ...

    pclose(pout);
}

fclose(perr);
close(pfd[0]), close(pfd[1]);
```

As Andrew pointed out, if `command` generates lots of output/errors, you must handle the streams more carefully (see comments below).

Comment: Interesting use of a pipe to capture the error stream from the child process in a separate stream.  I don't think reusing `stdout` and `stderr` is a good idea, though, as that makes your implementation unsuitable for general use.  And *reading* from them certainly is not a good idea.  And you have to be real careful reading from both streams - if the child process fills up the pipe for the stream you're *not* reading from, your two processes will deadlock - you won't get any output from the stream you're trying to read from because the child process is trying to write to the other stream.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my response to fix the stream names (pout, perr). With regard to reading the streams: strictly speaking, it would be necessary to use select() to determine which stream needs to be read at each moment. (But that would make the code overly complicated to handle simple situations).

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Andre Luis da Silva Monteiro is really brilliant.
Just for additional choice, I am adding the proposal below. Instead of popen(), a new process is forked, supplying all connecting pipes - stdin, stdout and stderr.
The comment of Andrew Henle applies as well.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* These definitions are for issuing error messages.
 */
#define WarningMessage( ErrMess) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Warning: %s\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (ErrMess) )
#define ErrorMessage( ErrMess) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Error: %s\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (ErrMess) )
#define ErrorMessageFromCall(Func) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Error from function %s(): Errno: (%d) [%s]\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (Func), errno, strerror(errno))
#define ErrorMessageFromCall1(Func) fprintf(stderr, "%s() (file %s, line %d): Error from function %s()\n", \
    __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (Func))

#define buffLen 1024
#define MAX_EVENTS 10


int main()
{
  int pip0[2], pip1[2], pip2[2];
  int FDChildStdin, FDChildStdout, FDChildStderr;
  int iret, i;
  pid_t PID, PID1;
/* This is the command to execute and its arguments. See execve() for more details */  
  char Command[]="/usr/bin/ls";
  char *argv[3]={ [0]="ls", "-l", };
  char *envp[1]={};
  
  char buff[buffLen];
  int FDEpollInst;
  struct epoll_event ev, events[MAX_EVENTS];
  int nfds;

  iret= pipe( pip0);
  if( iret)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
    return -1;
  }
  iret= pipe( pip1);
  if( iret)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
    return -1;
  }
  iret= pipe( pip2);
  if( iret)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
    return -1;
  }

  PID= fork();
  if( PID < 0)
  {
    ErrorMessageFromCall("fork()");
    return -2;
  }
  if( PID == 0)
  {
/* here we are in the child process  
   This child process will be reading from pip0, writing to pip2 and pip3. 
   * This will be the new stdin, stdout and stderr.
   * The process should not know about the previous file descriptors. */     
    close( pip0[1]);
    close( pip1[0]);
    close( pip2[0]);
    
    iret= dup2(pip2[1], 2);
    if( iret == -1)
    { /* This will be probably the last message written to the original stderr from this process... */
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "In child process: pipe()");
        return -1;
    }
    iret= dup2(pip1[1], 1);
    if( iret == -1)
    { /* This will already go to the stderr pipe. See the previous call. */
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
        return -1;
    }
    iret= dup2(pip0[0], 0);
    if( iret == -1)
    { 
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "pipe()");
        return -1;
    }
    close( pip0[0]);
    close( pip1[1]);
    close( pip2[1]);

    iret= execve(Command, argv, envp);
    if( iret == -1)
    { 
        ErrorMessageFromCall( "execve()");
        return -1;
    } 
/* Now, the Command runs in this process. No more control in this code. */
    
  } else
  {
/* here we are in the parent process  */
/* The child process will be writing to pip0, reading from pip2 and pip3.
 * This process will use the oposite ends of the pipes. */     
    FDChildStdin= pip0[1];
    FDChildStdout= pip1[0];
    FDChildStderr= pip2[0];

   FDEpollInst= epoll_create1(0);
   if (FDEpollInst == -1) 
   {
       ErrorMessageFromCall( "epoll_create1()");
       return -2;
   }

   ev.events = EPOLLIN;
   ev.data.fd = FDChildStdout;
   if(epoll_ctl(FDEpollInst, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, FDChildStdout, &ev) == -1) 
   {
       ErrorMessageFromCall( "epoll_ctl()");
       return -2;
   }
   ev.events = EPOLLIN;
   ev.data.fd = FDChildStderr;
   if(epoll_ctl(FDEpollInst, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, FDChildStderr, &ev) == -1) 
   {
       ErrorMessageFromCall( "epoll_ctl()");
       return -2;
   }

   for( ;; )
   {
/* Wait for data from child. Timeout 10 seconds. 
 * Would be better to decrease timeout in subsequent calls,
 * if loop is repeated because of interrupt (errno == EINTR). */
       nfds = epoll_wait(FDEpollInst, events, MAX_EVENTS, 10000);
       if( (nfds == -1) && (errno != EINTR))
       {
           ErrorMessageFromCall("epoll_wait()");
           return -2;   
       } 
       if( nfds > -1) break;
   }
   if( nfds == 0)
   {
       printf( "No data from child available within the timeout.\n");
   }
   for( i= 0; i< nfds; i++)
   {
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLIN) printf( "file is available for read(2) operations.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) printf( "file is available for write(2) operations.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) printf( "Stream socket peer closed connection, or shut down writing half of connection.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLPRI) printf( "exceptional condition on the file descriptor.\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLERR) printf( "Error condition happened on the associated file descriptor\n");
     if( events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) printf( "Hang up happened on the associated file descriptor.\n");

       if( events[i].data.fd == FDChildStdout)
       {
           printf("Event in stdout of child.\n"  );
           iret= read(FDChildStdout, buff, buffLen);
/* Do not be tempted to read again, when not all data have been read at once.
 * This is a blocking fd! It is necessary to check for presence of data before another
 * attempt of read. Else it may hang forever. 
 * Same below for stderr. */           
           fprintf( stdout, "stdout from child: ");
           write( 1, buff, iret);
       } else if( events[i].data.fd == FDChildStderr)
       {
           printf("Event in stderr of child.\n"  );
           iret= read(FDChildStderr, buff, buffLen);
           fprintf( stdout, "stderr from child: ");
           write( 1, buff, iret);
       } else 
       {
           printf("Event in unknown fd!\n"  );
       }
   }
/* Wait for child to catch return code. */
    PID1= wait(&iret);
    if (PID1 < 0)
        printf("Failed to wait for process %d (errno = %d)\n", (int)PID, errno);
    else if (PID1 != PID)
        printf("Got return status of process %d (status 0x%.4X) when expecting PID %d\n",
               PID1, iret, (int)PID);
    else if (WIFEXITED(iret))
        printf("Process %d exited with normal status 0x%.4X (status %d = 0x%.2X)\n",
               PID1, iret, WEXITSTATUS(iret), WEXITSTATUS(iret));
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(iret))
        printf("Process %d exited because of a signal 0x%.4X (signal %d = 0x%.2X)\n",
               PID1, iret, WTERMSIG(iret), WTERMSIG(iret));
    else
        printf("Process %d exited with status 0x%.4X which is %s\n",
               PID1, iret, "neither a normal exit nor the result of a signal");
}
  return 0;
}
```