# get failed output back

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to run a script and output the result in the console. It works, but there is a

small problem i'm facing right now.  If the "script" file is writed/coded wrong i get as output something like:

```
 syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting $end puts
```

which is very good that it tells me somehting is wrong with the code inside the script file, but in my code line:

```
printf("%s", path);
```

it dosent print that to me and i want it to print it so i can display it on the screen. Please help me out

```
 fp = popen("our script...is here", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        /* Handle error */;


    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s", path);


    status = pclose(fp);
```

Ps: just to make it more clear i'm using xcode and dont mind the code in C or C++

Comment: Yes i dont mind example if it in C or C++

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection and with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900577/c-popen-wont-catch-stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `fgets()` reads only from stdout of the stream. To capture `stderr`, you can simply redirect it to `stdout`:

```
 fp = popen("./script 2>&1", "r");
```

Now both the stdout and stderr will go stdout which your C code can read from.

Note that once you have redirected as above there's no way to differentiate stdout and stderr.

Comment: Can i get a complete example? please. As i know how to load the script, but need to print what wrong also

Comment: All you need to do change the one line as above and have some syntax errors in your script to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to care about the stderr - `popen()` handled only stdout:

> Conversely, reading from a "popened" stream reads the command's standard output,

The shell error will be printed to stderr - which popen() does not handle.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, could you please give a example on how to use it in the code to avoid any other problems and to also help others??

Comment: Ok - then I'll not finish the example - looks that one solution is already accepted.

Comment: Thnaks alot for your time, but someone already had a good solution. :)

Comment: I'm just wondering how you want to decide if the script exited with or without error.  Typically you have to distinguish between stdout and stderr - but if this fits your needs, it's ok.