# stderr output when using popen in C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, stderr

when I use this simple program to get the standard output of the process, I also somehow get the standard error of the process, although the man page for `popen` says that only the standard output is redirected. Is it possible that this is related to the shell that is used when forking a process with `popen`? `errEr` is a simple program outputting to `stderr` (`cerr << "hello";`). I'm using RHEL 6.4. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    FILE *fd = popen("errWr", "r");
    char str [1024];
    while (fgets(str, 1024, fd))
    {
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's `errWr`? Does it actually output anything to `stderr`?

Comment: its just a simple program outputting to `stderr` ( `cerr << "hello";`)

Comment: Are you sure that your program print  to `stderr`? Maybe it's just output directly from `errWr`? Maybe you should try to append something in your program, to be able to distinguish the outputs. Something like `cout << "=>" << str << "<=" << endl;`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900577/c-popen-wont-catch-stderr

Comment: Are you sure you're not just receiving stderr as normal, rather than via the pipe?

Comment: You could avoid the `stderr` being printed by redirecting it: `FILE *fd = popen("errWr 2>/dev/null", "r");`

Comment: It's not a good thing to mix `<stdio.h>` and `<iostream>` calls in a program.  Both use buffered streams and possible undefined behaviour can arise of mixing them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the output from `stderr` in your program using `popen`.

Following simple example shows, that error stream from started application is printed in terminal, without being read in your program. `popen` redirects only `stdout` stream and `stderr` stream is not affected, so it's just printed to terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    FILE *fd = popen("errWr", "r");
    char str [1024];
    while (fgets(str, 1024, fd))
    {
        cout << "=>" << str << "<=" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```