# Using C++ with popen( "findscu -v" ) cannot get the output message in ubuntu18.04

Tags: c++, popen, dcmtk

dcmtk3.6.3

I used C++ to code the function of popen("findscu -v", "r").
I want to get the output message of findscu to save in file.
But it only print to the console, i cannot save to file.

1. //--verbose verbose mode, print processing details

FILE * fstream = popen("findscu --verbose", "r");
The output message of findscu is print to console.

char * p = fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fstream);
p is NULL, and the buff is nothing.

2. But if i use this code:
   //--help  print this help text and exit
   FILE * fstream = popen("findscu --help", "r");
   It does not print to the console.

char * p = fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fstream);
p is not NULL, and the buff has the output message.
That is what I want.

What is the differents of this two cases?
How to get the message from case 1?

thanks.

ubuntu18.04 
C++ 
dcmtk3.6.3 
findscu

```
//C++ dcmtk findscu
FILE * fstream = popen("findscu --verbose", "r");

char buff[10240] = {0};
char * p = fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fstream);

cout <<  buff << endl;
```

I expect get output info from the buff, not from the console.
Case 2 is what i want.
Case 1 is what i dont want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c popen won't catch stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900577/c-popen-wont-catch-stderr)

Comment: thanks your reply. But Stdout is also not work.

Comment: What do you mean?  Does adding `2>&1` not help?

Comment: Why don't you specify an appropriate logger configuration file with findscu's --log-config option? This would allow you to direct all output immediately to a file. Also in case you are only interested in the C-FIND response datasets, you should try one of the --extract options.

Comment: `findscu` outputs to `stderr` but you are trying to capture `stdout`