# Why is faketime command skipping section of code

Tags: c++, popen, chrony, usefaketimers

I have a cpp code that I'm trying to run with faketime command. I'm running it on two identical computers. They're both running RHEL 7. I noticed that when I run my code, on one computer, it totally skips my popen call.

My code is essentially

```
char ntp[]= "192.168.1.200";
    FILE *jitter;
    char line[100];
    char *start;
    char * eol;
    char pps[] = "NTPS";
    jitter = popen("chronyc sources", "r");
        int i;
cout<<"reached here"<<endl;
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),jitter))
{
cout<<"line is\n"<<line<<endl;
 if(strstr(line,pps)){
        start = strpbrk(line,"#0+-");    
        cout<<"PPS is "<<start<<endl; 
        //find new line character and replace it with comma
        eol = strrchr(start,'\n');
        i=eol-start;
        start[i]=',';
    
        myfile<<start;
    }

    if(strstr(line,ntp)){
        myfile<<start;  
    }
}
    pclose(jitter);
}
```

I added a print statement of

```
cout<<"reached here"<<endl;
```

but when I run it with "faketime 'last friday 5pm' ./code", on one computer it never reaches the print statement for some reason while on the other it does. I searched online to no success (I'm not running a approximating algorithm, they have the same compiler and make file, etc. I'm literally doing a git pull of the code and running it).

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: So what does `popen` return? What is the value of `errno`?

Comment: @KamilCuk popen returns the value of chronyc sources. errno is 0 so it doesnt seem to be error-ing

Comment: You should show the code with the print statement in place - in case there is a flow-control issue preventing it from executing.

Comment: @Wyck done... (it was literally just after the while statement essentially printing the fgetsline). What is odd is that if I dont do the faketime command, itll print the line.

Comment: Where is the `if (jitter == NULL) perror("popen failed");` line?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I put one above the cout<<line is<< as well as immediately after the end of the while loop and still no difference in behavior or outputs

Comment: Is your claim that it is not executing the statement `jitter = popen("chronyc sources", "r");`?  Or is your claim that it is not executing the statement `cout<<"line is\n"<<line<<endl;`?  (Or both?)   It would be great if you posted the actual code instead of an excerpt.    `ntp`, `start`, `eol`, `pps` are all extraneous to your code sample as is.  Try again with something simple like `jitter = popen("ls", "r")`  Check the return value of `popen` for errors.

Comment: @Wyck When I run my code prefaced with faketime (so "faketime "5 days ago" ./code_run") it ignores the while fgets loop, so both. The actual code is the above plus it writing the chronyc sources call to a csv file so I didn't think you needed to see "myfile << line" statements"

Comment: To say it "ignores the loop" is incorrect.  Surely it calls fgets, passing in `jitter` as an argument (jitter is assigned the result of popen, which is either the file handle or nullptr).  The documentation for fgets says that it returns nullptr if A) there was an error (e.g. if popen failed) or B) if the EOF of the input stream is reached.  Which would make the condition for the loop false.  Probably A is happening.  That's why I said to try again with popen("ls","r") or because it's less likely to fail.

Comment: @Wyck ok so doing "ls" "works", but that still doesn't explain why chronyc sources "fails" when I prepend it with faketime on one computer but not the other nor why its causing it to not read in anything vs reading in chronyc sources when I don't prepend it. I need the chronycc sources call and not ls.
I added a `if(jitter==NULL){cout<<"popen failed<<endl;)}`. but it never prints that either

Comment: chronyc could be failing and writing its error message to stderr, which popen won't read (it only reads stdout).
 Try appending `2>&1` to the command.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900577/c-popen-wont-catch-stderr

Comment: @Wyck when I do that, it outputs that faketime failed "In ft_shm_init(), sem open failed: function not implemented" I have no idea what that means or how to resolve this

Comment: time to add a chrony tag to this question I think.  Also, update the question with all the relevant new information you have discovered.  Can you just run the command manually from the command line and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the issue was with SELinux. Apparently chrony doesn't interact well when SELinux is in enforced mode. I switched it to permissive and it behaves as expected now. I can call `faketime 'last friday 5pm' chronyc sources` as well as use it in my popen code